# Retrieve the PID for particular process name and kill it

Tags: shell-script

I am running a test server (local application), I want to fetch its process id and kill. How to do it?

I am running the `test-server` using command `nohup ./test-server &` and while verifying the PID for the process using

`ps -ef | grep 'test-server' | grep -v 'grep' | awk '{ printf $2 }'`

output:

```
svr-ser+   42707   42618  0 10:43 pts/2    00:00:00 /bin/sh ./test-server
svr-ser+   42709   42707  0 10:43 pts/2    00:00:00 /bin/sh ./test -Dserver_port=1099 -s -j test-server.log
svr-ser+   42734   42709  9 10:43 pts/2    00:00:01 /usr/bin/java -server -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xms1g -Xmx1g -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=100 -XX:G1ReservePercent=20 -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/urandom -Duser.language=en -Duser.region=EN -Dserver_port=1099 -s -j test-server.log
```

& Using the following command to kill the process,

`ps -ef | grep 'test-server' | grep -v 'grep' | xargs kill -9`

Output:

```
kill: cannot find process "svr-ser+"
Killed
```

How to retrieve only  `42707` and kill it, I want to kill very specifically the `./test-server` process nothing else.

Comment: my answer below focus on avoiding `grep -v grep` but why don't you use `awk '{print $2}` in first place ?

Comment: As an aside: I've never understood why people use signal _numbers_ when all the relevant commands let you use their _names_. OK, many people remember that `KILL` is `9`, but who remembers the numbers for `INT`, `TERM`, `HUP`, `ABRT`, and all the other signals?? And there's something so satisfying about typing `kill -KILL `… :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
ps -e -H -o pid,comm | awk '$2 ~ /test-server/ { print $1}'
```

Or its POSIX equivalent:

```
ps -Ao pid= -o comm= | awk '$2 ~ /test-server/ { print $1}'
```

to check pid

where

- `-H` do not print header
- `-o pid,comm` print only pid and command line
- `awk` filter on `test-server` (you may need to adjust this part (e.g. `$3 ~ /test-server/` and use `args` instead of `comm` to filter on command line arguments)

if OK, then run

```
ps -Ao pid= -o comm= | awk '$2 ~ /test-server/ { print $1}' | xargs kill
```

Comment: or:
    awk 'BEGIN{ while("ps --no-headers -C test-server -o pid" | getline pid) { system("kill " pid) } }'
or just killall test-server or pkill test-server

Comment: if `pgrep test-server` work fine, just use `pkill testserver` to kill it. my solutin aim at finding string in command's argument.

Answer (score 19):

To get the PID of something whose name you can describe by a regex, as you do with your `grep`, can simply be done using `pgrep test-server`, as in `kill -9 $(pgrep test-server)`.

But that's a detour that you don't have to take; `pkill` does it directly, `pkill -9 test-server`.

Answer (score 4):

What about this?

> nohup ./test-server & echo "$!" >test-server.pid

Then:

> kill "$(<test-server.pid)"

Also: killing with `SIGKILL` will most likely prevent a clean exit of the server; use `SIGTERM` (the default signal sent by `kill`) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use `killall` - kills processes by name.

`man killall` will show you usage.  It's quite clever.

Comment: On some UNIX systems (Solaris, for instance), `killall` literally does what it says - kills all processes. It's better to get used to using `pkill` instead. It will save you one day when you're not on a Linux system and you don't want the unexpected downtime. :)